# Como espaçar o "título fixo" de uma página e as postagens?

Tags: php, html, css

Durante a criação da página, resolvi colocar um "título" qual terá o nome do site e algumas abas para o usuário ser encaminhado; porém, ela sempre sobrepõe a primeira postagem:[image: Problema]

Sendo que cada postagem é assim:
[image: Postagem Padrão]

Usando PHP, CSS ou HTML, como posso fazer com que somente a primeira página do site tenha um recuo para não ser sobreposta por padrão?

[EDIT]
O meu problema foi resolvido, mas queria deixá-lo responsivo. Quando acessei o IP (o site) pelo meu celular, conforme eu aumentava o zoom, a barra de navegação ocupava mais espaço (ou seja, não havia como ler nada). Como posso fazer para arrumar isso?

Código:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.navigationbar
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black, darkgrey);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
}

.navigationbar img
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%
}

.navigationbar_spacer
{
    opacity: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
}


.postagem
{
    padding: 1%;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 33%;
    margin:  auto auto;
    background-color:#edebed;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

.postagem div
{
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #95bcf0;
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto auto;
}

.postagem h1
{ 
    font-family: "arial";
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: 
}

.postagem p
{
    font-family: "book antiqua";
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Chuto que esse "png test" esteja com `position: absolute; top: 0`. Tente colocar no body um `margin-top: 75px` ou o tamanho do "png test".

Comment: @Patrick ele esta com `margin: 0 auto; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como diz @Patrick, uma vez que a sua `navigation bar` ou `header` vais estar sempre presente ao longo das suas páginas a forma mais segura será adicionar ao CSS do seu contentor onde os seus posts estão alojados uma `margin-top: 50px;`.

```
.header{ 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #111;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.sub-container{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Pode ver o **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2XcCN/)** e faça scroll no display para ver o seu título fixo

Para vários `containers` no site eu usaria a seguinte estrutura:

```
<body>
    <div class="header">PNG TEST</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sub-container"><!-- texto --></div>
        <div class="sub-container"><!-- texto --></div>
        <div class="sub-container"><!-- texto --></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Uma vez que a técnica do layout fluído é o uso extenso de percentagens nos CSS, basta colocar a altura da sua barra igualmente com percentagem:

```
.header{ 
    height: 5%;
}
```

NOTA: No entanto é desaconcelhado colocar percentagens em alturas (`height`)

Comment: Circle, o problema é que eu terei VÁRIOS containers ao longo do site, mas eu achei uma solução e vou postar aqui.

Comment: @Lucas resposta actualizada

Comment: Circle, estou com mais um probleminha que eu coloquei na pergunta (em EDIT). Você sabe como solucionar?

Comment: @Lucas, resposta actualizada

Comment: Obrigado Circle; e olha que sacanagem: o único que eu não havia utilizado porcentagem era o height. Vou adicionar o código atual caso alguem queira utilizar futuramente.

Comment: Fazendo o que você disse em ambas as divs, a navigation bar fica minúscula e o método que eu fiz não funciona.

Comment: Consegue criar um fiddle para analisar melhor a sua questão?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mbq6d/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15780/discussion-between-lucas-henrique-and-circle).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma class no body de cada página, é algo bem utilizado, geralmente essa class é o nome da página.

sendo assim você consegue ter controle de qualquer elemento por página.

Exemplo:

```
.class-body .titulo{margin-bottom:20px;}
```

Assim você consegue controlar apenas em tal página, que isso pode acontecer

Por php é possivel pegar o nome da página atual aberta, você pode fazer uma condição pegando nome da página == 'voc digita a p^´agina que terá a alteração' dentro da condição pode chamar um css ou dar echo de brs que não é aconselhavel

Answer (score 0):

O que parece é que esse seu "header" está com `position` `fixed` ou `absolute` com `top` setado para `0`

De qualquer forma, seria assim o que eu faria

***CSS***

```
.header {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background:#e1e1e1;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.post {
    width:50%;
    padding:10px;
    background:#e1e1e1;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Pode acompanhar o resultado nesta **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/QnqsD/)**.

***OBS.: utilizei valores fictícios pois não tenho seu código como referência.***

Answer (score 0):

Como ideia adicional, eu fiz uma div com as propriedades de tamanho equivalentes às da barra de navegação e opacidade máxima; ou seja, ela ocupa o mesmo espaço que a barra de navegação, e como as postagens tem identação por padrão, a div não fica colada com o texto. O código foi:

```
<div class="navigationbar"> <!-- imagem --> </div>
<div class="navigationbar_spacer"></div>
```

Tendo navigationbar_spacer as mesmas propriedades de tamanho que navigationbar, ou seja, navigationbar sobrepõe exatamente o mesmo tamanho que navigationbar_spacer tem.

Comment: Tenta explicar melhor com algum exemplo, eu não percebi nada do que fizeste.

Comment: @JorgeB. resposta editada